# Having issue with .bat file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, command, cmd

I have mini recursive function which finds and hides all .mta files. It looks like that

```
For /r %1 in (*.mta) do attrib +h "%1"
```

When i'm trying to execute it from command Prompt manually, it works properly

[image]

I've created .bat file. The code looks like that

```
D:
For /r %1 in (*.mta) do attrib +h "%1"
pause
```

Tried to execute this file. Gettin' this screen

[image]

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: In general this link is pretty useful for these sort of problems: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
For /r %%i in (*.mta) do attrib +h "%%i"
```

(And name your file `.cmd`, it looks more modern.)

Don't use `%1`, that refers to your script's arguments, so it [will not work](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true). Use `%` at the command line and `%%` in batch scripts.

Answer (score 0):

`%1` is a command line argument passed to the batch file, which happens to be empty in this case. That means your `for` loop syntax is incorrect. Use some other variable name instead, like %f:

```
for /r %f in (*.mta) do attrib +h "%f"
```

If you'd used your version and don this:

```
c:\> yourbatch.bat f
```

then %f would've expanded to just 'f' and you'd get:

```
for /r f in (*.mta) do attrib +h "f"
```

which would also be incorrect.

Comment: used f, it gives message sytax of the command is incorrect http://prntscr.com/3s0t3

Comment: As Mat mentioned %1 can confuse, but it's also a legal for loop variable, the only problem was the missing second percent